# CUDA memcpy async is not returning immediately

Tags: optimization, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, data-transfer

Following is my code which tries to achieve non-blocking cuda memory copy host to device.

```
for (i = 0; i < ldu; ++i)
{
     cudaMemcpyAsync(dA+i*num_row, &A+i*LDA,
         num_row*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,streams[0]) ; 

}
```

Average time for each such call is around 10 microseconds. I have tried blocking version which takes 30 microseconds. 10 microseconds, for a non-blocking call seems a lot. A is allocated using cudaHostalloc. I run my code on machine equipped with 1 single Tesla C2050 , and I use cuda version 5.5 to compile the code. I have read that gpu PCI-transfer latency ( a bit irrelevant to non-blocking call, but to give an idea about the order of time) is around 5us. So it return time for a non-blocking call to be 10 us is a bit on higher side. Any thing I can do to speed it up?

Couple of  things that I tried were, putting an openmp pragma (which resulted in slow down), sending data using different streams ( which gave around the same average time)

Comment: Is this in windows or linux?  What time do you measure if you issue just a single call rather than a sequence of calls?

Comment: It is in linux. I'll get back to you about 2nd part in a moment

Comment: for a single call i.e. if I change ldu=1, then the return time is around 3.5 us

Comment: There seems to be a number of async copies that can be queued into a single stream, above which the queueing performance will slow down quite a bit.  This number seems to be in the 1000-10000 range.  So I am guessing, for your test that `ldu` is in this range.  Here is [my test](http://pastebin.com/ADfu10Gx).  Below 1000 queued copies, the average overhead is less than 3us.  Above 10000 copies, the average overhead is over 20us.  However  I believe you can replace your copy loop with a single call to `cudaMemcpy2DAsync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any thing I can do to speed it up?

I believe you can replace your copy loop with:

```
cudaMemcpy2DAsync(dA, num_row*sizeof(double), &A, LDA*sizeof(double), num_row*sizeof(double), ldu, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, streams[0]);
```

which should speed things up (at least from a call overhead standpoint) significantly.

You may have to play with your parameters a bit, as your names are somewhat confusing to me (maybe you are using column-major storage).  The `cudaMemcpy2DAsync` function is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g7f182f1a8b8750c7fa9e18aeb280d31c).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and post my results.

Comment: Now the cost is only about 3.4 us for whole send, which is equivalent to sending a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Fermi gpus has only one copy engine for each direction. So, all copy commands in the same direction are serialized, no matter they are async or not.